# What is the difference between getChildHtml and getChildBlock?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, blocks

In the description of the method of `getChildHtml` it is said **"Retrieve child block HTML"**
In the description of the `getChildBlock` method, it says **"Retrieve child block by name"**.
But what is the difference?

Comment: You can accept the answer by tick marking near to answer If it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, but for this we need to call the object of the child block?

Comment: No you just need to pass block name which you can find it from layout `XML` file

Comment: I wanted to say, for what purposes do we need to call a block object?

Comment: It's up to your requirements :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As name suggest [`getChildHtml()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L496) render the HTML of block if it find the block and [`getChildBlock()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L476) will return only the Block object if it finds any block.